# Breaking inner loop python

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, break

I want to exit just the inner loop where I have placed the break. Using continue works, but I thought break was supposed to exit the inner most loop yet it seems to exit the whole program. What's the deal with break?

```
counter = 0

while counter == 0:

    print "You enter a dark room with two doors.  Do you go through door #1 or door #2?"

    door = raw_input("> ")

    if door == "1":
        print "There's a giant bear here eating a cheese cake.  What do you do?"
        print "1. Take the cake."
        print "2. Scream at the bear."

        bear = raw_input("> ")

        if bear == "1":
            print "The bear eats your face off.  Good job!"
        elif bear == "2":
            print "The bear eats your legs off.  Good job!"
        else:
            print "Well, doing %s is probably better.  Bear runs away." % bear
            break

    else:
        print "You stumble around and fall on a knife and die.  Good job!"
```

Comment: `if` statements are not loops, so your `break` only applies to the outer `while` loop.

Comment: check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm), `if` is not loop, so `break` will break the whole `while`

Comment: This is quite morbid.

Comment: Blame Zed Shaw lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one loop in your code, and break is exiting it, "if" is not a loop, it is a statement...even if you have multiple, they are statements, and break, will "break" from your while loop, not "if" statement.

Comment: Got it. I was confused as the statement would continually execute since the initial condition was still met and mistook it for a loop.

Comment: no problem, the more you code, the better you get =)

Answer (score 1):

> `break`- Jumps out of the closest enclosing loop (past the entire loop
>   statement)

In your case thats exactly what it is doing. `if` is not a looping statement, its a control statement.

You have only one loop which is a `while`.